# Cannot install any version of ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I follow the install instructions it says that nothing can be installed be cause dependencies will not be installed. How do I fix this? Using ubuntu 12.04

here is the error I get

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-desktop-full : Depends: ros-groovy-ros-tutorials (= 0.3.9-0precise-20121230-1218-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-nodelet-core (= 1.7.13-0precise-20130104-0044-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-navigation-tutorials (= 0.1.1-s1357276030~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1357177371~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-filters (= 1.6.0-s1356885392~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1357273397~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-qt-gui-core (= 0.2.9-0precise-20121230-1132-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-vision-opencv (= 1.10.0-0precise-20130103-2233-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-perception-pcl (= 1.0.25-0precise-20130104-0111-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-common-plugins (= 0.2.7-0precise-20130104-0046-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-actionlib (= 1.9.11-0precise-20130102-2201-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-pipeline (= 1.10.1-0precise-20130104-0139-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-stage (= 1.6.7-s1357177365~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-robot-plugins (= 0.2.7-0precise-20130103-2333-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-common (= 1.9.22-0precise-20130103-0000-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-bond-core (= 1.7.9-0precise-20121230-1144-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1357260899~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-ros-comm (= 1.9.39-0precise-20121230-1434-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-driver-common (= 1.6.4-0precise-20130104-0045-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-executive-smach (= 1.2.0-s1357171161~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-dynamic-reconfigure (= 1.5.31-0precise-20130104-0028-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.15-0precise-20130104-0046-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-xacro (= 1.6.1-s1356886240~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-robot-model (= 1.9.32-0precise-20130103-0145-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-visualization-tutorials (= 0.7.3-s1357254450~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-geometry (= 1.9.28-0precise-20130103-0114-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-documentation (= 1.5.3-s1356885143~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-laser-pipeline (= 1.5.5-s1357268665~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo (= 1.7.6-s1357263540~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.4-s1357177152~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rviz (= 1.9.18-0precise-20130103-2233-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-diagnostics (= 1.7.9-0precise-20130103-0115-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-navigation (= 1.10.1-s1357270099~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1357170981~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52937/cannot-install-any-version-of-ros/) by [AlphaOne](https://answers.ros.org/users/4021/alphaone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi AlphaOne, welcome to ROS Answers! Is this a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install? Have you tried to install ROS and interrupted the process somehow? It seems like you may have broken packages in your package manager. Here are some ideas: http://askubuntu.com/questions/167688/how-to-fix-apt-get

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also faced this issue in Ubuntu 12.04, in my opinion both ROS fuerte and ROS groovy have installation issues for 3.5 version of kernel, but works fine with 3.2. Check your kernel version with `uname -a` in the terminal window and if it is 3.5, then you may need to reinstall your OS, go for Ubuntu 12.04 release, later version (viz. 12.04.2 etc) have a higher kernel.

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1